# Instanciate a temp static list head pointer in C

Tags: c, list, recursion

```
void add_tail_r(list ** head, int elem)
{

 list *current=*head;
 list *temp = NULL;

 if (current->next==NULL)
 {
   if (!(  temp=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list )) ))
     printf("Error");
     temp->elem=elem;
     temp->next=NULL;
     current->next=temp;
     return;
 }
 else
 {
    add_tail_r (current->next,elem);
 }
}
```

I have this recursive function that have to insert an element into the list but when the function is recursively called it goes into an infinite loop. 
How can I declare 'current' and 'temp' static if they are a self-declared types?
How can I fix this?

```
typedef
       struct list{
              int elem;
              struct list*next;
              } list;
```

Comment: If you want them to maintain their values for the recursive part you have to pass them along to the function.  Also is it a linked list you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm trying to not pass the two indexes in the function, I want to mantain them private in the header file if it is possible.

Comment: To make it sure, the add_tail_r is supposed to add the element to the last place?

Comment: Of course, it have to add an element in the tail of the list.

Comment: You don't have to use recursion for that, is that a requirement?

Comment: Your recursive `add_tail_r()` call should be `add_tail_r (&current->next,elem)` (to pass `list **` not `list *`), and you need to handle the case where `head` is `NULL` if you want this to work on an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

```
void add_tail_r (list* head, int elem)
{
    list* new = NULL;
    list* temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    new = (list*) malloc (sizeof (list));
    new->elem = elem;
    new->next = NULL;

    temp->next = new;
}
```

I hope I did not make any mistake, I am currently without a C-compiler.

The intended function of it is to take a list element and iterate forward through its `->next` pointer until we reach a NULL value, which means we've reached the end of the line. Once we are on that row we can allocate memory for a new element with `void* malloc (size_t size);`

Once we are on that part we can assign its `->elem` value  to our `elem`.

*Edit #1 This takes away the recursion part, if that is required then discard this.*

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef  struct list{
              int elem;
              struct list*next;
              } list;

void add_tail_r(list ** head, int elem)
{
 list *temp = NULL;

 if (*head == NULL)
 {
   if (!(  temp=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list ))))
   {
     printf("Error ..");
     return; 
    }
    temp->elem = elem;
    temp->next = NULL;
    *head = temp;

 }
 else
 {
    add_tail_r (&(*head)->next,elem);
 }
}

void print_list(list * head)
{
    list *tmp=head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n" , tmp->elem);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
list * my_head = NULL;

int main()
{

    add_tail_r(&my_head, 10);
    add_tail_r(&my_head, 8);
    add_tail_r(&my_head, 6);
    add_tail_r(&my_head, 4);
    add_tail_r(&my_head, 2);
    print_list(my_head);
    return 0;
}
```